# Local update site with remote features

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, update-site

I would like to create a lightweight eclipse update site that would only reference to feature or plugins in remote update sites, in order to have a single entry point for my team to install and update all the common plugins that we use for some projects.

But I don't find a way to reference these external features/plugins. I've create some archive mapping to the external update sites, but it keeps downloading all the artifacts when building the update site.

Is there a way to prevent that so that we just have the descriptor locally?

Comment: Why don't you simply give them an eclipse version where all the plugins are preinstalled?

Comment: Because we want to benefit from the update mechanism and we also want to allow people to add some plugins to their environment without having to reinstall them each time a new packaged version is delivered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that but you have to add the plugins and features via archives to your *site.xml*. Furthermore, it is important to not change the names and to include all plugins that are needed by a feature in the archive path. Here is a snippet of a real example:

```
<feature url="http://borisvl.github.com/Pdf4Eclipse/features/de.vonloesch.pdf4eclipse_1.0.1.jar" id="de.vonloesch.pdf4eclipse" version="1.0.1">
  <category name="Pdf4Eclipse"/>
</feature>

<archive path="features/de.vonloesch.pdf4eclipse_1.0.1.jar" url="http://borisvl.github.com/Pdf4Eclipse/features/de.vonloesch.pdf4eclipse_1.0.1.jar"/>
<archive path="plugins/de.vonloesch.pdf4Eclipse_1.0.1.201111161450.jar" url="http://borisvl.github.com/Pdf4Eclipse/plugins/de.vonloesch.pdf4Eclipse_1.0.1.201111161450.jar"/>
<archive path="plugins/de.vonloesch.pdf4eclipse.help_1.0.0.201111161450.jar" url="http://borisvl.github.com/Pdf4Eclipse/plugins/de.vonloesch.pdf4eclipse.help_1.0.0.201111161450.jar"/>
```

As you can see this includes the feature `de.vonloesch.pdf4eclipse_1.0.1.jar` from a github page. This features includes two plugins which were also added via `<archive ... />.`

The downside of this approach is that you must include any updated version of the feature by hand, but I do not think there is another possibility to include a foreign feature.

Answer (score 4):

You can aggregate other remote update sites if you provide a composite p2 repo that can point to one or more remote repos.  In your update directory, create 2 files:

**compositeArtifacts.xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?compositeArtifactRepository version='1.0.0'?>
<repository name='Local Artifact Repository Collection' type='org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.CompositeArtifactRepository' version='1'>
  <properties size='2'>
    <property name='p2.timestamp' value='1323486257091'/>
    <property name='p2.compressed' value='true'/>
  </properties>
  <children size='2'>
    <child location='http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8-I-builds/'/>
    <child location='http://download.eclipse.org/e4/updates/0.12-I-builds'/>
  </children>
</repository>
```

**compositeContent.xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?compositeMetadataRepository version='1.0.0'?>
<repository name='Local Content Repository Collection' type='org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository' version='1'>
  <properties size='2'>
    <property name='p2.timestamp' value='1323486257489'/>
    <property name='p2.compressed' value='true'/>
  </properties>
  <children size='2'>
    <child location='http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8-I-builds/'/>
    <child location='http://download.eclipse.org/e4/updates/0.12-I-builds'/>
  </children>
</repository>
```

Then you can use your update directory as input to `Help>Install New Software`

Comment: did not work for me. What should be the value for timestamp? should I change that value?

Comment: The timestamp is mostly meaningless.  What part didn't work?  What did you do?  Perhaps you should ask a new question.

Comment: Additional documentation can be found here https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Composite_Repositories_(new)